# How to get selected value of dropdown within gridview in asp.net using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview, which has multiple rows. One column is dropdownlist. I need to find the selected value of dropdownlist for each row.
When I view Page source , Its generating id StartHourDropDown for dropdown. But name for each dropdownlist is different for example grvRewardRulesDetails$ctl02$StartHourDropDown. So how to get selected value of dropdownlist of any nth row.

Comment: Add a part of your html so we can see the structure.

Comment: Can you post the page source?

Comment: <select name="grvRewardRulesDetails$ctl02$StartHourDropDown" id="StartHourDropDown">
    <option selected="selected" value="HH">HH</option>
    <option value="0">00</option>


   </select>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for the dropdown in gridView you can put

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="StartHourDropDown" runat="server" onchange='javascript:functionChange(this)' >
```

you can select from the dropdown using

```
functionChange(data)
{
    var currentDropDownValue = document.getElementById(data.id).value;
}
```

Comment: (-1) as there will be multiple dropdown not a single with different ID

Comment: Tried:var DropDown= document.getElementById('<%= StartHourDropDown.ClientID %>');

var currentDropDownValue = DropDown.options[DropDown.selectedIndex].value;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null
var DropDown= document.getElementsByName('grvRewardRulesDetails$ctl03$StartHourDropDown');

var currentDropDownValue = DropDown.options[DropDown.selectedIndex].value;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Comment: try putting alert for DropDown.SelectedIndex. i think then you will be able to fix the selected value out of it.

Comment: @user3264676 i have changed my code a bit. not sure with syntax errors. try this format.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery as follows

```
$("#grvRewardRulesDetails").eq(n).find("Select");
```

for value you can use

```
 $("#grvRewardRulesDetails").eq(n).find("Select").val()
```

The above will give you the nth dropdown list.

Here is an [equation API of jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: This works, but only if you only have a one column that has Drop Down Lists in it. Otherwise, you'll probably end up pulling in the wrong drop down lists. Also, you'll have to write a loop around it to get all the values.

Answer (score -2):

I like to add a CSS class to the DropDownList to make it easy to get with a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). This method has the advantage of not having to worry about ID's. It does mean that you will need to have jQuery. Most of the time websites already include it (it's included by default in the ASP.NET Web Forms New Site template). It's also available from [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery) if you're using Visual Studio.

You'll need a reference to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) in the header. Let's load it from the Google CDN. This is easy, because you don't have to download the script and place it in your site, and it's nice for the client because it will load faster due to caching. Alternatively, go download and self-host it.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="gvddl" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in your JavaScript.

```
function MyFunction()
{
    $(".gvddl") //do something with it
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use CSS. I have mentioned this.

Comment: Where have you mentioned this? Besides, we aren't really using CSS. We are just specifying a class for the DropDownList that will make it simple to get all of them using a jQuery selector. Please try what I have posted, I think you'll find it does what you're asking for cleanly and efficiently.

Comment: I'm beginner, I dont know how to use JQuery. So please provide me full details. otherwise provide me only javascript code. Hope you understand and dont mind

Comment: jQuery is purely JavaScript code. It's just a library you can add to your page that makes many JavaScript things much easier.

Comment: what I need to do with CssClass="gvddl"??

Comment: The reason we added CssClass="gvddl" is so that we can then use the jQuery selector $(".gvddl") which gets all elements that have a CSS class of "gvddl".

Comment: Okay, I got some down votes. Does anyone care to share why, as it will help me and user3264676?